# Dynamically generate lambda expression with constants from variables

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework

I've been troubleshooting an unusual issue with some EF 6 code where queries running with the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client driver are sometimes taking several minutes to return results even when the underlying query executes within 2ms. An example query would be as follows:

```
var result = users.Where(u => u.username == varUserName).FirstOrDefault();
```

This query might take several minutes to return, however if I replace the query with the same thing with a constant in the lambda function, it runs instantaneously:

```
var result = users.Where(u => u.username == "testUsername").FirstOrDefault();
```

To work around this issue, I can either write parameterised SQL queries, or I can manually generate an appropriate lambda expression tree:

```
var userParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Entity.User), "user");
var userNameField = Expression.Property(userParam, "username");
var userNameConstant = Expression.Constant(varUserName, typeof(string));
var equalUserName = Expression.Equal(userNameField, userNameConstant);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Entity.User, bool>>(equalUserName, new ParameterExpression[] { userParam });
var result = users.Where(lambda).FirstOrDefault();
```

Because this works, it begs the question: **is there a way to easily generate lambda expression trees which result in variables being directly included as constants, instead of references to variables?**

For example, something like this would be ideal:

```
var lambdaExpression = (u => u.username == varUserName).ReplaceVariablesWithConstants();
```

Comment: Didn't you meant: `var userNameConstant = Expression.Constant(varUserName, typeof(string));`

Comment: I certainly did, thanks @JeroenvanLangen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done relatively easy with `ExpressionVisitor` which evaluates the `ConstantExpression` members like this:

```
public static class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression<TDelegate> ReplaceVariablesWithConstants<TDelegate>(this Expression<TDelegate> source)
    {
        return source.Update(
            new ReplaceVariablesWithConstantsVisitor().Visit(source.Body), 
            source.Parameters);
    }

    class ReplaceVariablesWithConstantsVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            var expression = Visit(node.Expression);
            if (expression is ConstantExpression)
            {
                var variable = ((ConstantExpression)expression).Value;
                var value = node.Member is FieldInfo ?
                    ((FieldInfo)node.Member).GetValue(variable) :
                    ((PropertyInfo)node.Member).GetValue(variable);
                return Expression.Constant(value, node.Type);
            }
            return node.Update(expression);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's kinda hard. You need to modify the ExpressionsTree with a [ExpressionsVisitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654266.aspx). It would probably become something like:

```
var lambdaExpression = ReplaceVariablesWithConstants(u => u.username == varUserName);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your MSDN link combined with the other answer will solve my problem!