# Get combined Expression<TDelegate> from IQueryable

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Following on from a previous question ([Dynamically generate lambda expression with constants from variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759722/dynamically-generate-lambda-expression-with-constants-from-variables)), my goal is to apply a workaround to a large number of complex LINQ EF queries in existing code.

As an example, queries are built up as follows:

```
var query = Entities.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == varUserName);
query = query.Where(u => u.IsUserLocked == varUserLocked);
query = query.Where(u => u.LastModifiedAt > varLastModifiedAt);
```

And then results are derived as:

```
var results = query.ToList();
```

To work around an issue in the EF provider I am using, I have had to modify the Where() expressions as follows:

```
var query = Entities.Users.Where(OracleEFQueryUtils.ReplaceVariablesWithConstants<Func<Entity.User, bool>>(u => u.UserName == varUserName));
query = query.Where(OracleEFQueryUtils.ReplaceVariablesWithConstants<Func<Entity.User, bool>>(u => u.IsUserLocked == varUserLocked));
query = query.Where(OracleEFQueryUtils.ReplaceVariablesWithConstants<Func<Entity.User, bool>>(u => u.LastModifiedAt > varLastModifiedAt));
```

As can be seen, while this works, it results in very verbose code, and it also means that a large existing codebase must be migrated to use this new method.

**I am searching for an easy way to apply this method to all Where() expressions.**

So far I have thought of two approaches which I am researching:

- **Approach 1:** Inherit from System.Linq.Queryable and override Where() to add the necessary method call. Then change all affected files to be using my own class at the top of the file, instead of using System.Linq.
- **Approach 2:** Create a new method that takes an IQueryable, and processes the expression tree to return a new IQueryable that has had all variables replaced with constants, similar to the effect of manually calling my method on all Where() expressions.

I am preferring approach 2 because it intuitively feels cleaner, however I run into the problem of not being able to find the combined expression tree to amend. I have found the IQueryable.Expression property, but I cannot find how to proceed from there.

For reference, my implementation of OracleEFQueryUtils is as follows:

```
class OracleEFQueryUtils
{
    public static Expression<TDelegate> ReplaceVariablesWithConstants<TDelegate>(Expression<TDelegate> source)
    {
        return source.Update(
            new ReplaceVariablesWithConstantsVisitor().Visit(source.Body),
            source.Parameters);
    }

    class ReplaceVariablesWithConstantsVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            var expression = Visit(node.Expression);
            if (expression is ConstantExpression)
            {
                var variable = ((ConstantExpression)expression).Value;
                var value = node.Member is FieldInfo ?
                    ((FieldInfo)node.Member).GetValue(variable) :
                    ((PropertyInfo)node.Member).GetValue(variable);
                return Expression.Constant(value, node.Type);
            }
            return node.Update(expression);
        }
    }
}
```

I may be attempting to do something that is unsupported by the framework, however I look forward to any ideas! Thanks.

Comment: Would an extension method on the `IQueryable` provide a cleaner usage pattern for you?

Comment: Can't quite understand what you're trying to do here and why you would want to do it.   Why would you want to replace variables with constants in the query?  Wouldn't that reduce hits on the query plan cache and lead to a big decrease in performance?

Comment: Perhaps there's a really good reason why what you're doing is unsupported by the framework.

Comment: @Mick I completely agree that it's a ludicrous workaround, but it's the only way to make the query actually return a result - because of what I'm figuring is an incompatibility between the version of the database and the version of the EF provider I have to use. I think that it is cleaner to use this workaround instead of writing parameterised SQL queries (which incidentally, work fine but are displeasing to my team). Ultimately, I found a workaround which I am seeking to apply cleanly, and it seems to be an interesting general problem which allows for learning about expressions and such.

Comment: @mariocatch I hadn't considered this at all. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: It seems like you've asked for help getting a solution to work for a problem, but you've not actually specified what the problem is.  Parameterised SQL queries are displeasing to your team ?  Do they like exposing systems to sql injection attacks ?  Do they not like their queries having cached execution plans?

Comment: @Mick, parameterised SQL queries are fine, but using EF even with the workaround that Jeff's answer has allowed for, means that if the schema is changed then it is a matter of refactoring an entity class, instead of searching through a codebase to find all queries and hopefully change them all. SQL injection attacks might be possible if I worked to make them possible I guess, but it's not really related to this question. And as for cached execution plans, it's a trade-off that we can live with for our purposes - we have thousands, not hundreds of thousands of queries per second. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look into creating extensions to override the methods for the query operations you want to support.  Depending on how far you want to go with this, it can produce some nice looking code.

```
public interface IOracleQueryable<T> : IQueryable<T> { }

public static class OracleQueryExtensions
{
    public static IOracleQueryable<TSource> AsOracleQueryable<TSource>(
            this IQueryable<TSource> source) => new OracleQueryable<TSource>(source);

    public static IOracleQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
            this IOracleQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate) =>
        Queryable.Where(source, Replace(predicate)).AsOracleQueryable();

    private static Expression<TDelegate> Replace<TDelegate>(Expression<TDelegate> expr) =>
        OracleEFQueryUtils.ReplaceVariablesWithConstants<TDelegate>(expr);

    private class OracleQueryable<TSource> : IOracleQueryable<TSource>
    {
        public OracleQueryable(IQueryable<TSource> source) { Source = source; }
        private IQueryable<TSource> Source { get; }

        public Expression Expression => Source.Expression;
        public IQueryProvider Provider => Source.Provider;
        public Type ElementType => Source.ElementType;
        public IEnumerator<TSource> GetEnumerator() => Source.GetEnumerator();
        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() =>
            GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Then all you need to do now is to remember to add `AsOracleQueryable()` to your queries.

```
var query = Entities.Users.AsOracleQueryable()
    .Where(u => u.UserName == varUserName)
    .Where(u => u.IsUserLocked == varUserLocked)
    .Where(u => u.LastModifiedAt > varLastModifiedAt);
```

It should even work fine in the query syntax.

```
var query =
    from u in Entities.Users.AsOracleQueryable()
    where u.UserName == varUserName
    where u.IsUserLocked == varUserLocked
    where u.LastModifiedAt > varLastModifiedAt
    select u;
```

Comment: I will try this approach because I like the idea of just adding a single method call at the start of any affected query - it is clean and it limits the mysterious workaround to having a minimal impact on the codebase. Stand by!

Comment: I tried it and it works perfectly. It will meet the requirement of allowing predicates to be chained and modified with only one change at the start of each query. Thanks for the inventive answer!

Comment: Great answer. But do you think anyone should actually be doing this?

Comment: @Mick: I don't see why not. If you wanted to extend or override the functionalities that are provided by EF or other linq provider, this would be a nice way to achieve that. I understand your concern in your comments on the question, but that's besides the point.